# Oracle Unique Constraint with Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Does `Oracle` support constraints with expressions like so?

Notice Z = 'N'

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT U_A_KEY UNIQUE(X,Y,Z = 'N');
```

Is this `Unique constraint` possible?

Example:

```
INSERT INTO A VALUES('X','Y','N');  --OK
INSERT INTO A VALUES('X','Y','Y');  --OK
INSERT INTO A VALUES('X','Y','Y');  --OK
INSERT INTO A VALUES('X','Y','N');  --VOLIATION
```

Comment: Does that mean that you want to have at most one record with Z='N' for each x,y combination?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe this gives an idea

```
drop table tq84_n;

create table tq84_n (
   x number, 
   y number, 
   z varchar2(10)
);

create unique index tq84_n_x on tq84_n (
  case when z = 'N' then x || '-' || y 
       else null
  end
);
```

Later:

```
insert into tq84_n values (4,5, 'N');

insert into tq84_n values (9,6, 'Y');
insert into tq84_n values (9,6, 'Y');

insert into tq84_n values (4,5, 'Y');

insert into tq84_n values (4,5, 'N');
```

Last one throws:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SPEZMDBA.TQ84_N_X) violated
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest approach in this case is generally to create a function based index.  Something like

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX u_a_key
    ON a( (CASE WHEN z = 'N' THEN x ELSE null END),
          (CASE WHEN z = 'N' THEN y ELSE null END) );
```

If z is not 'N', both CASE statements evaluate to NULL and Oracle doesn't have to store the x & y values in the index structure (making the index smaller).  If z is 'N', the x & y values are both stored in the index and the index behaves just like any other compound index.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in that sitaution is to create a column e.g. `Z` in your case, which has:

- A particular value (e.g. your "N") in the case I need it to be unique
- Null otherwise, meaning unknown: two unknown values are considered to be not equal to one another.

Then you can create your unique constraint `UNIQUE(X,Y,Z)`.

Add two rows with equal X and Y and Z="N" and you'll get an error; add two rows with equal X and Y both with Z=null and you won't.

Comment: Column Z can hold another value which must pass the constraint. Question updated with SQL for clarify, thanks.